# How to add a new user in drupal 7 programmatically ?My custom module defines a form with custom fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

Hi being a newbie to drupal , kindly guide how to add a new user , i know user module with user_save can be used but how and where to implement it ? 
Do i have to write this function in submit handler of my custom form below-

```
function registerme_newform($form, &$form_state) 
{
$form = array();
$form['account details'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Account Details'),
'#description' => t('Enter Personal Credentials'),
);
$form['account details']['first name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('First Name'),
'#default_value' => t('Be sure of your first name'),
'#attributes' => array(
'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Be sure of your first name'}",
'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Be sure of your first name') {this.value = ''}" 
  , ), 
   ); 
 $form['account details']['last name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Last Name'),
'#default_value' => t('Be sure of your last name'),
'#attributes' => array(
'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Be sure of your last name'}",
'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Be sure of your last name') {this.value = ''}" 
   , ), );

 $form['account details']['email'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('E-Mail'),
'#required' => TRUE,
'#default_value' => t('Email acts as username.Dont forget it!'),
'#attributes' => array(
'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email acts as username.Dont forget 
 it!'}",
'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Email acts as username.Dont forget it!')
 {this.value = ''}" 
   , ), 
 );

$form['account details']['password'] = array(
'#type' => 'password',
'#title' => t('Password'),
'#maxlength' => 60,
'#size' => 60,
'#required' => TRUE,
'#description' => t('Password should be atleast 6 characters long.'),
);

 $form['home'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => 'Home Address',
'#description' => t('Enter Personal Residential Credentials')
 );

 $form['home']['street'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'Street Address',
 );

 $form['home']['city'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'City',
 );

 $form['work'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => 'Work Address',
 '#description' => t('Enter Official Address')
 );

 $form['work']['street'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'Street Address',
 );

 $form['work']['city'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'City',
);

 $form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => t('Register Me'),
 );

 return $form;

 }

 function registerme_newform_validate(&$form, &$form_state)
 {
 if($form_state['values']['account details']['first name']=='Be sure of your first
 name')
 {
  form_set_error('first name',t('Please enter your first name'));
 }
 } 
 function registerme_newform_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
 {
 dsm($form_state); 
  }
```

Also would like to know how will values be entered in database , i mean how will these custom fields be added to database? Kindly guide thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First of all please check if the first name is allowed user name. I recommend you providing another field to enter username as its not uncommon that username is already used by somebody else.  Then also check that there are no users registered with the given email address.

```
function registerme_newform_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['account details']['first name']=='Be sure of your first
  name') {
  form_set_error('first name',t('Please enter your first name'));
  }
  // TODO: Provide user with a chance to enter a name ( drupal user name )
  // Also do the following two checks and report an error.
  // check using user_load_by_name($form_state['values']['account details']['first anme'])
  // check using user_load_by_mail($form_state['values']['account details']['email'])
}
```

Next in your submit function map the form values to an array that could be passed to user_save as shown bellow. If you want to know exactly how other fields map, use the devel module to inspect the structure by vising an already existing user profile.

```
function registerme_newform_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $new_user = array(
    // The below name field must be unique.
    'name' => $form_state['values']['account details']['name'],
    'pass' => $form_state['values']['account details']['password'],
    'mail' => $form_state['values']['account details']['email'],
    'init' => $form_state['values']['account details']['email'],
    'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['account details']['first name']))),
    'field_last_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['account details']['last name']))),
    // Map all the extra fields to user objects as shown above.
    ...

    'status' => 1,
    'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'roles' => $roles,
  );

  // $account returns user object
  $account = user_save(null, $new_user);
  //after user_save you can use the following code to send notification email.
  drupal_mail('user', 'register_no_approval_required', $account->mail, NULL, array('account' => $account), variable_get('site_mail', 'noreply@mysite.com'));
}
```

Comment: how will these additional fields be added? i mean in database how will these additional fields get added or the user object has nothing to do with it? @D34dman

Comment: In Drupal 7 you can visit 'admin/config/people/accounts/fields' to attach new fields to user profile. Once the fields are configured then they can be made available in user registration form ( there is a checkbox in the field settings that allows this ) or can be filled up later. While programmatically adding a user you have to fill these fields ( as i have explained in the answer), and Drupal would take care of saving them in the database.

Comment: Thanks but being a custom form how can i mimic the registration process as in drupal 7 core? @D34dman

Comment: I have modified the answer.

But if your idea is to modify the user registration form, then i suggest you use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id). Replace the FORM_ID with the 'user_register_form' in our case.

If you just want to add new fields to user registration, the field settings mentioned in my previous comment has the provision to make them appear in the user registration form. 

In case you want to print the form out you can print the output of drupal_render(drupal_getform('user_register_form')); to a block or page.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a different approach to this problem.  I created an entity form (https://drupal.org/project/entityform)
where I prompt for key user information. I have also installed the profile2 module  allowing me to create alternate profiles. When the form is submitted it triggers a rule. That rule allows me to create the user, create a linked profile and then send an email to the administrator with a link to the new user entry allowing them to review and activate.

A nice alternative if you dont want to solve via PHP or want to create additional content on creation.

Comment: Interesting approach. Are you doing some sort of validation?